# Web Farm Framework: how do I access the application?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-farm, web-farm-framework

I have installed and set up the new Microsoft Web Farm Framework in a UAT environment with a controller machine, a primary, and a secondary server.
 I have installed one of our in-house applications on to the primary server and it has been successfully provisioned across to the secondary.

My question is, how do I then access the application? Normally, I would access it like http:\machinename\applicationname\, where machinename is the name of the server it is hosted on, but if I do this then I will be addressing the primary server directly. Would I not then be bypassing the server farm?

I have tried accessing the server via the below url http:\mis-uat-002\testfarm/reviewer
where mis-uat-002 is the name of the farm controller, testfarm is the name of the farm, and reviewer is the name of the application. When using this url I get a "502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server." error.

If I access the application directly via http:\mis-uat-003\reviewer (mis-uat-003 is the primary farm server, reviewer is the application) then it works no problem.

Is there some additional set up that needs to be done in order for the farm controller to do its job?

It should be noted that this is a UAT environment so is not on a domain of any sort. However, if this was successful and the WFF came out with V1.0 fairly soon, we would be looking to run this on a Windows domain.

Comment: I think you would do better posting your question on ServerFault.com.

Comment: I thought that after creating the thread, bit too late though. Could a mod please move this to serverfault?

Comment: Yep, creating another thread there might not be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Use the domain or IP of the load-balancer.

Comment: I missed the bit about the 502 earlier. 502 means "I'm trying to pass stuff through from elsewhere, but messing up", so the fault is with the LB, but beyond that I can't tell.